# Reactjs component in an external js file does not load sometime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a very basic ReactJs component.

I created an html file. Code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="I`enter code here`SO-8859-1">

    <title>Basics of React</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example"></div>


    <script src="../build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="../js/ReactBasic.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The js file code is below

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>This content is from a React Component!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

The problem is that when i try to run the same. It does not show the React Component that i ma trying to render. However the same piece of code if I embed in an html file it works fine. 
This issue is not with the examples that come with the React libraries, but just with htmls that i have created. This clearly indicates that there is no loading issue.

I am new to React and hence wanted to confirm what could be the problem here.

Comment: Is your code (second snippet) provided in ReactBasic.js?
Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Can you provide more of `ReactBasic.js`?

Comment: Yes the code is in ReactBasic.js and that is all that ReactBasic.js has. There is no error in the console. I checked it as the first thing when it didnt work.

Comment: You need to require React in your js file. React has to be required/imported in every file that it's being used in. It works when you have the files together because you have React and ReactDOM in the HTML being loaded. But they aren't being loaded in the JS file so it has no idea what ReactDOM is.

Comment: @erichardson30 i tried to include a require in my js file but started getting this error "ReferenceError: require is not defined". All that i added was  var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

Comment: Also, i am not using npm to run my code. It is simple html file and js file. Just wanted to let you know. The code examples from React also do not have a require.

Comment: Hmm....okay. Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108536/discussion-between-ramanuj-srivastava-and-erichardson30).

Comment: The issue is resolved, I removed the require from js files and copied the js file in the same folder where HTML file was. It started working when I did that. This is quite strange as this should never be a problem and never has been for me. Thanks @erichardson30 for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using npm, this is occurring due to the path for your JS file. It is not able to find your JS file, therefore not being loaded into the DOM.

To resolve this you have two options :

1. Put your JS and HTML file in the same directory and update the path in the HTML file
2. Use absolute paths to the JS file located in a separate directory.